# How is it possible that a single 1.6 GB cumulative update file get PC or server fully patched?

Tags: windows, updates

Our servers do not have access to the internet so we manually download CU files and install them.

Everyone keeps telling me all I need is the the latest CU file to get my PC or server up to date.

in 2020 there was been 4 CU releases: Jan (1.6 GB), Feb (1.6GB), March (1.6GB) and April (1.6GB)

Could someone explain how  it is possible that the April CU (KB5001347)can only be 1.6 GB?

SO if my Server 2016 has not been patched in 2 years, do I only need to install KB5001347 (April 2020) ?

The question is this: I'm confused that different Cumulative Updates are nearly the same size. If they contain all previous patches, I would expect each subsequent update to be larger than the previous update!

Because they are all the same this, I need to know: for my offline (not connected to the internet) Windows Server that is quite a bit behind on updates, do I only need to download and install the latest Cumulative Update, or do I need to download each of the CUs released since my computer was last updated?

Comment: That's why they are called cumulative, they include all past updates in that class, security or platform updates. There may be other non roll up updates that are not security or platform.

Comment: No I wouldn't say that a server needs ONLY the critical update rollups, as some updates will be packaged based on installed components (like .Net), but it will contain all updates for the core system deemed appropriate for ALL customers. In this case you need to understand that when they ship you an updated DLL, they are shipping you the latest version. when they started adding fixes for this months update, they started from last months version of the DLL, so by installing the April version of it, you are also getting all the March, Feb, and Jan updates to it already built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to download the latest available CU, as a rule of thumb. If you need to install prior updates you will be notified of this.

The total size of the updates doesn't vary much based on how they are packaged. Many updates are modifying the same files, and so only the most recent version of that file needs to be replaced in order for all previous patches and improvements to be applied. This is a simplification, and there are other facts involved, such as the compression employed and other things.